# Touchpad pinch zoom not functional in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04, mouse, touchpad

I am using ubuntu 22.04LTS and I am facing issue with touchpad functionalities. The two-finger zoom in zoom out pinch moving left-right is not working. First i thought its just problem with chrome version that Im using but then i tried with downloaded images on various softwares like chrome, shotwell viewer, image viewer, etc.

I have dual boot in my laptop so i know there are no hardware issues as touchpad works completely fine in windows.

Is there a case that ubuntu drivers are not up to date or doesnot encode such functionalities?

My laptops specifications_
ubuntu 22.04LTS

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

1. Your system should support multi gesture feature.
2. Check if the wayland protocol is enabled by using the cmd `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`
   and the output should display Wayland
3. Open your chrome browser and go to **chrome://flags** and search for Ozone platform and from the dropdown select Wayland and relaunch the browser. This should fix your problem

Comment: i am not expert in this but somewhere i read that wayland is incomaptible with nvidia gpu and i am using rtx3060......right now output of "echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE" on my terminal is "x11"

Comment: @HARSHDEVMURARI, from what I understand, Nvidia + Wayland is a lot better these days. Have you tried switching your session type and checking whether your everyday workflows work without issues?
If Wayland works for you, this may also fix it for you. It did enable gestures in Chrome for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the same problem i had, probably you could try below. I solved that by doing following, but not sure which is actually the solution:

- remove `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`
- in terminal, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events enabled`
- reset BIOS setting to default,
  https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/de/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t570/20ha/troubleshoot/lpt001165